# How do you treat ':' when it's part of a JSON node name?

Tags: json, wordpress, reactjs, react-native

I am looking at a JSON output from my wordpress site, and I'm trying to pull in the featured image of the post to my app. However, I've run into a little problem with a ':' in one of the node names.

the node name is 'wp:featuredmedia' and I'm trying to pull in the href that's sitting under it.

in my react native code, I have:

```
      <Image
          source={item.wp:featuredmedia.href}
          />
```

Any ideas how to resolve this ?

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.theContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.topicTitle}>MY POSTS</Text>
    <FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={this.state.data.id}
    renderItem={({item}) =>
      <View>
            <Image source={item['wp:featuredmedia'].href} />
             // the line above throws an error stating that it's 
             // not an object. Further that it's undefined. 
            <HTMLView
              value={item.title.rendered}
              styles={styles.topicTitle}
            />
            <HTMLView
              value={item.excerpt.rendered}
            />
      </View>
    }
    />
  </View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a JSON object, you can access it like this instead `item["wp:featuredmedia"].href`

Comment: I tried <Image
              source={item.['wp:featuredmedia'].href}
              />
And I get back "Unexpected Token".

Comment: my mistake `item['wp:featuredmedia'].href` no full stop after `item`

Comment: <Image source={item['wp:featuredmedia'].href} /> throws an error. :-(

Answer (score 0):

May be try:

```
      const href = "wp.featuredmedia"; // this is a string
     <Image
        source={item[href].href}
      />
```

Excuse me for the double quotes; I answered from my mobile

Comment: I just updated the code to show where and how this stuff fits in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bracket notation:
`item['wp:featuredmedia'].href`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: I'm getting back "Unexpected token" as a response to this line:

          <Image
              source={item.['wp:featuredmedia'].href}
              />

You took out the dot notation in your suggestion. I added it back, otherwise, the app throws an error in either case.

Comment: I just updated the code to show where and how this stuff fits in.

Comment: Here's a pen showing the bracket notation: [PEN](https://codepen.io/reynicke/pen/BqBWBK?editors=1011)
If that does not work for you, it has to be something with the data structure. Not accessing the data.