# Pulling Data from JSON with React-Native

Tags: json, wordpress, reactjs, react-native

What's wrong with this picture ? :-)

I'm trying to pull values from my wordpress JSON objects.

I must not be addressing them the correct/proper way with React-Native.

Can someone direct me as to how to form the correct console log statement ?

As it stands right now, the variable 'theMediaLink' is coming up 'undefined' in the console log. :-(

```html
  state={
    data:[]
  }

  fetchData = async() => {
    const response = await
    //response
    fetch('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/')
    //posts
    const posts = await response.json();
    this.setState({data:posts});

    const theMediaLink = `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/` + `${this.state.data.featuredmedia}`;
    console.log('theMediaLink_value: ', theMediaLink);
  }
```

I should add that the fetch is retrieving data as I use it later on with a FLATLIST to pull the posts. My question is I must be misforming the call, but how ?

Comment: when using `await` i don't think you need to do `response.json()`

Comment: Another thing, `setState` is asynchronous. but you can use it's callback argument to run code just after the state has been updated: `setState({key:value}, () => {...})`

Comment: please  check the value of  this.state.data.featuredmedia. Do console.log( this.state.data.featuredmedia)  I think it is undefined.

Comment: it is undefined. :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is more an issue of understanding of React rather than React Native.

Try this:

```
fetchData = async () => {
  const URL = 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'

  const response = await fetch(URL)

  const posts = await response.json();

  return this.setState({ data : posts }, () => {
    const { data } = this.state

    const theMediaLink = `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${ data.featuredmedia }`;

    console.log('theMediaLink_value: ', theMediaLink);
  });
}
```

Since `setState` is asynchronous, you won't be able to see the state update right away, that's why the `callback` is for.

More info [on how to setState asynchronously and use its value after right here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: Gotcha. Ok. I had bypassed that little detail about state that it's async. Ooops. Well that cleans up my code very nicely. It wasn't that awful but it's a lot more straight forward in this form. 

The only reason I'm trying to set those constants above is because I can't seem to form the proper call to get the json object > 'wp:featuredmedia', where the : is causing havoc with the call. RN throws a fit every time I do. As shown here > 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519548/how-do-you-treat-when-theyre-part-of-a-json-node-name/